Errno 2 no such file or directory "website_content.txt"
I'm gettin a file not found error, the one on the title, and I'm a beginner.
Can someone help?
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Headers = {"user-agent":"my user-agent"}

URL = "www.myurl.com"

def monitor_website_changes():
    while True:
        r = requests.get(URL, headers=Headers)
        with open("website_content.txt", "r") as file:
            previous_content = file.read()
        if response.txt == previous_content:
            print("website content has changed")
        with open("website_content.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(response.txt)
        time.sleep(1)

monitor_website_changes()

I'm building a script that tracks website changes, trying my very best to avoid the urlib library because of my difficulties understanding it. If it's possible I would like to solve the problem sticking to the 3 libraries utilized before.

I guess when you run the script for first time the file not exists so you get the error.
I restructure the problem a little bit:

when run try to load the file content
if the file is not found, return a dummy string
periodically check the website content with this string
if there's change, save the page to file, update string and goto step 3.

import time

import requests


def get_prev_content(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f_in:
            return f_in.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "dummy"


def monitor(filename, url):
    prev_content = get_prev_content(filename)
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)

        resp = requests.get(url)
        if prev_content == resp.text:
            print(".")
            continue

        print(f"{url=} changed, writing to {filename=} !")

        with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
            f_out.write(resp.text)

        prev_content = resp.text


url = "https://news.ycombinator.com/"
filename = "website_content.txt"

monitor(filename, url)

Prints:
...

.                
.                                              
url='https://news.ycombinator.com/' changed, writing to filename='website_content.txt' !
.

...


Thanks for your help, I have a question though, it looks like your code is checking for URL changes, what if the webpage changes without the URL changing? (I think I expressed myself badly, I wanted to track the changes of a specific webpage, I don't know if it affect the code you wrote for me significantly).
Thanks in advance

@RiccardoMelis The code checks if the HTML code returned from the server changes (if there's change - the server returns different HTML - the text is written to the file and notification is printed)

if I wanted to make it one time only, and than exit the program, how would you change the code you gave me?

@RiccardoMelis Then try to remove while True:, sleep and change continue to return

if I do that it exit without telling me anything, and if I add an else: statement, it tells me that the webpage changed, I think that is because the initial html text extracted from the page and the content of the website_content.txt file are always different at the beginning since the latter is empty at the first iteration
